# QWebEngineView and leaflet.js slow performance

Tags: python, qt, qml, folium, qwebengineview

I am making desktop app in Python (3.8.10) using QML frontend (Qt 6.4.1)

The principle is that I take data from a CSV file and load it into a pandas dataframe. The data contains coordinates that I want to display on a map using the folium library. Since I also want to display all the data, which can have thousands of records, I need to use clusters (folium.plugins.FasterMarkerCluster)
https://deparkes.co.uk/2016/06/24/folium-marker-clusters/

I create a map instance in a python class, insert points and create clusters

```
@staticmethod
def add_all_crime_types(map: MapObject, df: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    # Removing duplicates 
    df_filtered = df.drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='first')
    # Adding points to MarkerClusters and then adding MarkerClusters to the map
    folium.plugins.FastMarkerCluster(data=list(zip(df_filtered['x'], df_filtered['y'])), callback=DEFAULT_CALLBACK).add_to(map.m)
```

Then I convert the map instance into a string and send it to the frontend, where I load it using the webView.loadHTML(string) method

```
Item {
    id: item_showMap

    Connections {
        target: backend

        function onGetHTML(html) { webView.loadHtml(html) }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#d4d4d4"
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.rightMargin: -320
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: -320
        anchors.topMargin: 1

        WebEngineView {
            id: webView
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Component.onCompleted: backend.create_default_map()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, despite using clusters, performance is very poor, especially when scrolling. It is possible that hardware acceleration is disabled? Or some other feature? Maybe If there is another, more performance friendly, way to render the points.

I have tried another marker styling, using marker clusters and faster marker clusters.

Comment: Did you try to use `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts);` and `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL);` to speed up the rendering?

Comment: ...switching from debug to release compiler solved the problem for me.
https://forum.qt.io/topic/52360/qwebengineview-is-very-very-very-slow

Comment: When does `getHTML` is emitted?